# Memory access on 32/64 bit Windows, freeze

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, memory, 64-bit

So I have this old laptop, a **Lenovo ThinkPad T510** and I tried upgrading it's RAM from 2GB to 2*4GB (8GB). I was on a Windows 8 x32, and it worked, but only 3 out of 8GB were usable.

So I tried to install a x64 version of Windows without luck (I was booting from usb and after the Windows logo the laptop shut down and rebooted). So I put back the old 2GB stick and installed x64, now it worked. But if i try to boot with the 8GB on the x64 system, I go in a reboot loop.

Ran memtest86, froze at 54% at accessing memory.

What should I do ?

Comment: Is there a firmware update available for your laptop?

Comment: No, I already have the latest BIOS version but sadly I cannot find any memory timings or frequency configurations, no matter where I look.

Answer (score 2):

- Try to memtest each 4GB module independently.
- Update the BIOS.
- Check (on lenovo site) if the module models you have are compatible with the T510. DDR3-L may be incompatible (has different voltage than standard DDR3 module).

Comment: DDR3-L as far as I know supports both 1.5V and 1.35V voltages. That's why I bought it in the first place, @Overmind

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but the incompatibility may arise due to BIOS setting detection problems, not the voltage itself.

Comment: In BIOS they were detected, it showed that I had 8GB's installed, @overmind

Comment: Correct detection is insufficient for correct functionality.